# Alternate DNS server outside of domain

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-controller

I'm managing a small network that only has a single DC, which is running DNS. When I'm doing maintenance in the server in order for users to keep internet connectivity I have to configure a alternate DNS server (like 1.1.1.1) on each desktop.

Are there disadvantages of me doing this configuration on every desktop (maybe even through a GPO)? Meaning, is it good practice to do so in small companies with only one DC?

Comment: good practice is using DHCP for clients

Comment: Why are you performing server maintenance during production hours? Why do you have just a single DC? Address those issues and you'll solve your problem.

Comment: @joeqwerty It's the only time I can perform maintenance, I work in an MSP and the working hours coincide with the clients production hours. Regarding the single DC server, well it's a question of money, I'm there twice a month, they rather have the servers down 2 hours per month than paying more licences. They are a very small client, it's not really a problem, there are only 2 people working at lunch time when I'm restarting servers. 
The reason I've posted the question is because I've always been curious if there is a downside to configuring a public DNS as alternate on clients desktops.

Comment: @djdomi I use DHCP to assign IPs, but I don't think it's related to what I asked, or am I missing something?

Comment: OK, well... is it good practice? No, it isn't. Should you do it? If that's what you have to do then that's what you have to do.

Comment: @joeqwerty ok, so maybe the best thing is for me to only do it in the desktops that really need it (for internet connectivity) and not do it on a company wide level. Thanks